# Validação de Token Laravel (Passport)

Tags: laravel, angular

Desenvolvi uma api em `Laravel`. Está tudo certo, tudo funcionando.

O `Front-End` está sendo desenvolvido em `Angular`. Gostaria de saber se há algum método disponibilizado pelo `passport` para validação de `acess token`.

Exemplo: Angular tem um `token` => Envia a Api => Api (`Laravel`) valida se é um `token` válido => Retorna `sim` ou `não`.

Pois isso seria necessário após o tempo de espiração do token, necessitando gerar assim um novo.

Estou usando `Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS` e `Laravel Framework 6.17.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tem como e mesmo se tivesse não é viável validar o token no frontend, se quer validar um token, ou receber outro após expirar, é necessário enviar um request ao servidor.

O passport valida o token através do middleware, que pode ser usado no Controller ou na própria rota:

```
Route::get('/users', 'UserController@index')->middleware('auth:api');
```

Você pode envia `Accept: application/json` no header pra receber a resposta em json se o token está válido, caso a resposta venha 'Unauthenticated' você precisa enviar um novo request de login pra gerar outro token.

Comment: Isso mesmo que eu queria. E é o `backend`mesmo que vai validar. O `frontend` só vai mandar e receber a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo fortemente que utilize a geração/revogação/validação do token diretamente no laravel, assim como realizar as devidas configurações de tempo de expiração desejado por alguns motivos tais como:

- O seu token da API, serve para acessar recursos da API, enquanto seu token angular, para acessar recursos do Angular
- Laravel contem uma estrutura consolidada pro desenvolvimento de API, tal como segurança... Procurar maneiras de validar a segurança dentre diferentes frameworks não é um suporte nativo do framework Laravel, o que significa que provavelmente você deixará brechas na segurança do token
- É mais fácil trabalhar com o token do framework, do que dar toda essa volta

Espero, depois de análise do que está escrito, que consiga seguir o caminho certo !!

Comment: Amigo, entendi. Mas o token que quero validar é do próprio passport, só que nesse momento está sendo manipulado dentro do angular, é isso que gostaria de validar novamente. Desculpe minha ignorância se sua resposta responde minha pergunta.